# Data retrieve late from `asyncStorage` in react-native in drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a user preferences screen in my app in which data is managed using `asyncStorage`. Whenever I change some value in preferences, I need to reflect that change in other screens of the app. But it does not show changes immediately but shows them when I reload the app. What should I do ..?

I am fetching data using:  `multiGet()` in `ComponentWillMount()` and `ComponentDidMount()` and transitioning between screens with `drawerNavigation`.

I have even tried to use a global variable to reflect the changes but I does not help. Should I use `redux`?  What should I do ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use redux. Definitely, if you want to pass some props over the app it is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

use async-await to fetch data from asyncStorage

like this

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // update your ui
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Comment: I am already using async-await. But it does not fetch the data as soon as I move to another screen.

Comment: did you use async-await to save data ?

Comment: Yes I did @Vinil Prabhu

Comment: when are you retrieving data in 2nd screen ? in componentDidMount()?

Comment: I am retrieving data in  `componentDidMount()` as well as tried using `componentWillMount()`.

Comment: i did `async componentDidMount() {
  let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
  await this.setState({ user: user });
  }` and then updated ui based on state value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189126/discussion-between-neha-and-vinil-prabhu).